# Is this a bug in TypeScript 0.9.5? Choosing the right function overload... named function type vs inline function type

Tags: typescript

//I created a issue on codeplex: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2112

```
declare module TestBug {
    interface ListIterator<T, TResult> {
        (value: T, index: number, list: T[]): TResult;
    }
    interface testcase<T> {
        func1<T2>(iterator: ListIterator<T, T2[]>): string;
        func1<T2>(iterator: ListIterator<T, T2>): number;

        func2<T2>(iterator: (value: T, index: number, list: T[]) => T2[]): string;
        func2<T2>(iterator: ListIterator<T, T2>): number;
    }
}

var tc: TestBug.testcase<string>;
//This returns as a number, but should match first implementation of func1 and return a string
var result1: number = tc.func1(v=> [v]);
//When not using the typed function interface... it seems to work fine?
var result2: string = tc.func2(v=> [v]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The typescript people replied to the issue I opened. It is a bug... but it is already fixed in the development branch. So it should be fixed in the next release.